# How to get drive's filesystem information in winapi?

Tags: c++, winapi

I have disk letters like C:/ D:/ E:/ and I have paths like //./PhysicalDrive0 , //./PhysicalDrive1.

How can I get information about filesystem?

For example:

Drive C:/ is NTFS or better: //./PhysicalDrive0 is NTFS

Please for snippet

Comment: [`GetVolumeInformationW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getvolumeinformationw) seems to do what you're looking for.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to ask about a file system of a physical drive. A physical drive carries partitions, which in turn may be formatted with (possibly different) file systems.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at `GetVolumeInformation()`, Take a look at [this API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getvolumeinformationa).

An example, [found here](https://www.installsetupconfig.com/win32programming/windowsvolumeapis1_4.html):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int wmain()
{

      // + 1 is for NULL
      WCHAR volumeName[MAX_PATH + 1] = { 0 };
      WCHAR fileSystemName[MAX_PATH + 1] = { 0 };
      DWORD serialNumber = 0;
      DWORD maxComponentLen = 0;
      DWORD fileSystemFlags = 0;

      if (GetVolumeInformation(
            L"C:\\", L"\\MyServer\MyShare\"
        volumeName,
        sizeof(volumeName),
        &serialNumber,
        &maxComponentLen,
        &fileSystemFlags,
        fileSystemName,
        sizeof(fileSystemName)) == TRUE)
      {
            wprintf(L"GetVolumeInformation() should be fine!\n");
            wprintf(L"Volume Name: %s\n", volumeName);
            wprintf(L"Serial Number: %lu\n", serialNumber);
            wprintf(L"File System Name: %s\n", fileSystemName);
            wprintf(L"Max Component Length: %lu\n", maxComponentLen);
            wprintf(L"File system flags: 0X%.08X\n", fileSystemFlags);
      }
      else
      {
            wprintf(L"GetVolumeInformation() failed, error %u\n", GetLastError());
      }
      return 0;
}
```

The output:

[image: volume info]

Comment: Thank you :) Could you tell me one more datail? What is L"\\MyServer\MyShare\" parameter? I need only C:\\

Comment: try passing `NULL` for the second param and see what it returns